# CKEditor4: Alternative skin in inline mode

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I want to use CKEditor4 in inline mode, but have trouble using an alternative skin (the default skin Moono works fine).

I downloaded an alternative skin and tried to activate it in config.js via:

```
 config.skin = 'minimalist';
```

(I also tried some other ways (inside event handler) with the same result):

The toolbar always shows up with Moono skin -- but what makes me wondering very much is, that the skin files are definitively loaded from the alternative skin directory. Also skin.js is loaded (which is not loaded for Mono skin.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly it is a bug of the minimalist skin.

I tried an different skin and found out, that it is displayed correctly. So it seems to be a "feature" of the minimalist skin.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is related to what you encounter, but note that **only one skin can be used on one page**. So if you have two editors and one of them is initialised with the Moono skin, then the second one will use it as well. This limitations comes from the fact that all CSS selectors in skins files would need to contain skin name - otherwise they would conflict with each other.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I use only one skin at a time. My case works perfectly with the BootstrapCK skin -- only the minimalist skin shows no sign of changes.